# WordPress audio plugin: Display mp3 link if browser dosen't support Flash

Tags: wordpress, plugins, audio

I'm using the 1pixelout audio player plugin (version 1.2.3) in WordPress (version 2.7.1) to post short audio clips.  When I load the site in a browser that doesn't have a flash plugin, there's no fallback method to play the audio.

Is there any way to get the plugin to gracefully degrade to provide a vanilla link to the MP3 file when flash isn't available on the browser?  Or are there alternative players that would provide this functionality?

Answer (score 0):

Check out PodPress or PowerPress. They are the main Podcast plugins for WordPress.

Answer (score 0):

Check out Uber Audio for Wordpress.  It has both a flash and HTML5 fallback so it plays in most if not all browsers.  It's a great plugin.

You can find it at http://WordpressAudio.com